# Tableau Weighted Average Per Capita Calc not aggregating right

Tags: formula, aggregate-functions, tableau-api

I am trying to create a simple revenue per person calc that works with different filters within the data. I have it working for a single record, however, it breaks and aggregates incorrectly with multiple records.

The formula I have now is simply `Sum([Revenue]) / Sum([Attendance])`. This works when I only have a single event selected.  However, as soon as I select multiple shows it aggregates and doesn't do the weighted avg.

[image]

Comment: Can you share a workbook or screenshots? The formula you have (`SUM([Revenue]) / SUM([Attendance]`). I don't think that's the calculation you're actually using because you're getting `SUM([Revenue] / [Attendance])`

Comment: your formula seems to be correct... can you share workbbok

Comment: Are `Revenue` or `Attendance` calculated fields?

Comment: SUM(Revenue) / SUM(Attendance) should be correct

Answer (score 0):

I'm making some assumptions here, but hopefully this will help you out.  I've created an .xlsx file with the following data:

```
Event     Revenue   Attendance
Event 1   63761     6685
Event 2   24065     3613
Event 3   69325     4635
Event 4   41996     5414
```

Inside Tableu I've created the calculated column for Rev Per Person.

Finally, in the Analysis dropdown I've enabled `Show Column Grand Totals`.  This gives me the following:

[image: Original Tableau Viz]

**Simple Fix**

The problem is that all of the column totals are being calculated using the SUM aggregation.  This is the desired behavior for Revenue and Attendance, but for Rev Per Person, you want to display the average.

In Analysis/ Totals / Total All Using you can configure the default aggregation.  Here we don't want to set all of them though; but it's useful to know.  Leave that where it is, and instead click on the `Rev Per Person` Grand Total value and change it from 'Automatic' to 'Average'.

[image: Changing Default Aggregation]

Now you'll see a number much closer to the expected.
[image: Final Viz with nearly expected value]

But it's not exactly what you expect.  The average of all the Rev Per Person values gives us $9.73; but if you take the total Revenue / total Attendance you'd expect a value of $9.79.

**Slight More Involved Fix**

First - undo the simple fix.  We'll keep all of the totals at 'Default'.  Instead, we'll modify the `Rev Per Person` calculation.

```
IF Size() > 1 THEN
    // Grand Total
    SUM([Revenue]/[Attendance])
ELSE
    // Regular View
    SUM([Revenue])/SUM([Attendance])
END
```

Size() is being used to determine if the calculation is being done for an individual cell or not.

More information on Size() and similar functions can be found on Tableau's website here - https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/functions_functions_tablecalculation.html

Now I see the expected value of $9.79.

[image: Correct Value]